# Applying a function on a given column

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I would like to apply a given function "passFailFunc" on a given column of my dataFrame.
Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = letters[1:10], B = sample(1:20, 10))
=> 
   A  B
1  a  7
2  b 15
3  c  4
4  d  9
5  e 17
6  f  8
7  g 18
8  h 14
9  i 16
10 j 12
```

And function definition

```
passFailFunc <- function(x, th) {
  if (x>th) { 
    status='fail'
  } else {
    status='pass'
  }
  status
}
```

I would like to create a new column "status" where numbers from column B are considered 'pass' if they are below threshold, say th=15, and fail otherwise

```
df$status <- lapply(df$B, function(x) passFailFunc(x, 15))
=> 
   A  B status
1  a  7   pass
2  b 15   pass
3  c  4   pass
4  d  9   pass
5  e 17   fail
6  f  8   pass
7  g 18   fail
8  h 14   pass
9  i 16   fail
10 j 12   pass
```

This works fine, it seems to be doing the job. However when I try:

```
factor(df$status)

Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

the status column is actually a vector

```
> is.vector(df$status)
[1] TRUE
```

Question: How to correctly generate the 'status' column ?

Comment: Next time add `r` tag to your R questions, this way people will actually see your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lapply` is just a pretty `for` loop and it is always better to try avoiding them in R. Your specific function is easily vectorised using `ifelse`

```
df$status <- ifelse(df$B > 15, "fail", "pass")
```

If you still prefer using it as a function, you could try using `data.table` package for it

```
passFailFunc <- function(x, th) {
  ifelse (x > th, "fail", "pass")
}

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, status := lapply(.SD, function(x) passFailFunc(x, 15)), .SDcols = "B"]
```

The reason that `factor(df$status)` doesn't work for you is because `lapply` returns a list (read `?lapply` documentation) you can see it by using `str(df)`. if you still want to do it in your original way, use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

The reason that `is.vector(df$status)` returns `TRUE` is because a `list` is a vector in R.

Try running

```
is.vector(list(a=1))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: David, Understood, thank you very much. I have taken the ifelse solution as per your recommendation. Thx for your time and effort !

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the error by:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(A = letters[1:10], B = sample(1:20, 10))
```

Using your `passFailFunc`

```
df$status <- unlist(lapply(df$B, function(x) passFailFunc(x, 15)))
factor(df$status)
#[1] pass pass pass fail pass pass pass pass fail pass
#Levels: fail pass
```

or

```
factor(df$B<=15, labels=c('fail', 'pass'))
#[1] pass pass pass fail pass pass pass pass fail pass
#Levels: fail pass
```

or

```
c('pass', 'fail')[(df$B>15) +1]
#[1] "pass" "pass" "pass" "fail" "pass" "pass" "pass" "pass" "fail" "pass"
```